# Running axios script from localhosted server frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, frontend, backend

I have a frontend that is hosted on my local host. Once the user fills in all the data on that frontend, they click a button that then starts a function called startBot() which uses axios. If i just run startBot using the command line and never the server, the script works perfectly, but when I use the function from the server, axios uses my browser details to send information. Here is my code:
This is the function that runs when the user clicks the button to run startBot():

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
const fuzzyset = require('fuzzyset.js');
var helperFunctions = require("./helperFunctions");

const DELAY = 1500;

const getSupremeProducts = async () => {

    let supremeHome = `?p=${new Date().getTime()}`;

    await helperFunctions.redirectTo(
        supremeHome, 
        DELAY, 
        "Successfully connected to Supreme!", 
        "Error accessing Supreme site, retrying...");

    // direct link to the backend of the site
    let backendLink = "/mobile_stock.json";

    const products = await helperFunctions.redirectTo(
        backendLink, 
        DELAY, 
        "Successfully connected to backend!", 
        "Error accessing Supreme site, retrying...");

    return products.data;
}
```

Here is the helperFunctions file:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const qs = require('qs');

// constants
const RETRY_DELAY = 1000;

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

// creating a simple axios session so all cookies are stored throughout the checkout process
const session = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://www.supremenewyork.com`,
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
  });

// timer function for delays
const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// function for simple get requests
const redirectTo = async (redirectLink, delay, successfullMessage, errorMessage) => {

    while(true){

        try{
            const getRedirect = await session.get(redirectLink);

            if(getRedirect.status === 200){
                if(successfullMessage != null){
                    console.log(successfullMessage);
                }
                await timer(delay);
                return getRedirect;
            }

            else {
                console.log(errorMessage)
                await timer(delay);
            }
        }

        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            await timer(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when i run getSupremeProducts() in the terminal with no server, it works great, but running it from the frontend it messes everything up (btw, I'm using webpack, that's why i can run the node module script from html) and causes this error:

[image: Errors]

Any help is greatly appreciated! I just need to figure out how to run this code from the frontend but let axios not use the server details to run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. That's CORS, you'd have to change the HEADERS in the remote server to allow requests from your domain and port. If you don't have control over it then there're a few options*.

- Add your local address and port in the server allowed domains
- If you are just developing locally and don't have control over the server, you can disable CORS on your browser temporarily!
- Create a local proxy server, your Frontend makes the request to the Proxy server and the proxy server to the remote server (I usually stick with this one, just make sure it has the first point the allowed hostnames and ports etc)

You can read more about it here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I'm running my server using serve-static that just runs html with the budle.js, and css files. -------------------------------------
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

connect()
    .use(serveStatic('../frontend'))
    .listen(8000, () => console.log('Server running on 8000...'));

Comment: Your requests are going to supremeneywork.com from botapi.supremenewyork.com:8000, they are different. supremenewyork.com does not allow botapi.supremenewyork.com:8000... not sure you're following. Now, if you're client app makes the request to `botapi.supremenewyork.com:8000` that's same hostname and port. Or, as I've mentioned create a proxy to make the request to wherever you want and takes requests from your client side...

Comment: Ahhh okay, now I understand. Is there a link to how I can do the third option above?

Comment: You can find a working example here in one of my repositories ( https://github.com/heldrida/starling-round-up/blob/master/api/index.ts ); but the idea is to write the call server-side, which takes your request computes it and redirects it.

Comment: What if I have proxys already? Can't I use those to mask where the request is coming from? I just tried it by using the proxy attribute in axios andit didn't work. I'll give your repo a look

Comment: I had a quick look into "botapi supremenewyork" and seems that there's a few projects that provide you with a wrapper for the supremenewyork API, these are proxy. If you already have that locally, all you need to do is to make your client-side app to send the requests to it. That's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212744/discussion-between-punkbit-and-frankied003).